# Adding database connection to spring boot project dinamically

Tags: spring-boot

Good morning. I am creating a spring boot application where in the login form the user enter the username, password and environment it is trying to connect. The problem is that I created a microservice that receive the credentials and the database id but it is not able to customize jdbcTemplate according to the databaseId. I'd like to add/remove database sources dinamically without change the respective beans.

My application.property is

```
spring.datasource.connections[0].url=
spring.datasource.connections[0].username=
spring.datasource.connections[0].password=
spring.datasource.connections[0].driver-class-name=

spring.datasource.connections[1].url=
spring.datasource.connections[1].username=
spring.datasource.connections[1].password=
spring.datasource.connections[1].driver-class-name=
```

and I defined the following classes:

```java
package com.app.authentication.configs;

public class DataSourceContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setDataSourceKey(String dataSourceKey) {
        contextHolder.set(dataSourceKey);
    }

    public static String getDataSourceKey() {
        return contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDataSourceKey() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}

package com.app.authentication.configs;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DataSourceProperties {
    private String url;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String driverClassName;
}

package com.app.authentication.configs;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

public class DynamicDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DataSourceContextHolder.getDataSourceKey();
    }
}

package com.app.authentication.configs;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.class)
public class MultipleDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.connections")
    public List<DataSourceProperties> dataSourceProperties() {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap(List<DataSourceProperties> dataSourcePropertiesList) {
        Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSourcePropertiesList.size(); i++) {
            DataSourceProperties properties = dataSourcePropertiesList.get(i);
            DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(properties);
            dataSourceMap.put("dataSource" + i, dataSource);
        }

        return dataSourceMap;
    }

    private DataSource createDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        if (properties.getUrl() == null || properties.getUsername() == null || properties.getPassword() == null || properties.getDriverClassName() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("DataSourceProperties' properties can not be null");
        }

        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(properties.getUrl())
                .username(properties.getUsername())
                .password(properties.getPassword())
                .driverClassName(properties.getDriverClassName())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dynamicDataSource")
    public DynamicDataSource dynamicDataSource(@Qualifier("dataSourceMap") Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap) {
        if (dataSourceMap.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("DataSourceProperties list can not be empty");
        }

        Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>(dataSourceMap);

        DynamicDataSource dynamicDataSource = new DynamicDataSource();
        dynamicDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSourceMap.get("dataSource0"));
        dynamicDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);

        return dynamicDataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dynamicDataSource") DataSource dynamicDataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dynamicDataSource);
    }
}
```

but it fails because it is not able to read the connections definition, so, I always get just one record and properties url, username, password and driver-class-name are always null.

Sorry for my english; have a good one.